# Поиск по части имени в списке

Tags: python

Всем привет! Очень нужна помощь. С помощью os.listdir() получаю список всех директорий по заданному адресу, имена директорий - две уникальные буквы и цифры. Собственно, вопрос: как узнать индекс элемента в списке, зная только эти две уникальные буквы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил задачу с помощью fnmatch